# Can't start Windows Phone Emulator after installing Mango SDK

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I've been working with the Windows Phone SDK 7.0 for a long time on my computer. Now I installed the SDK 7.1 (beta) and for some reason I can't start the emulator. I'm getting this error:

> The program can't start because MFPlat.DLL is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

I don't have that dll on my system, but I grabed it from another computer and put it in System32 and in the emulator directory, but still no luck. I tried reinstalling the SDK twice with no luck either.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling all WP7 dev related tools and reinstalling from scratch? Downloading a DLL from the web and installing it isn't always a great idea. Does your system meet all the requirements from Mango SDK B2?

Comment: My system meets all the requirements for Mango. It seems that for some reason I didn't have that dll. @arterius solution worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I'll suggest first of all you need that files. In my system I found **mfplat.dll** in four different places. Also I found **mfplat.dll.mui** file (also in four different locations), which maybe also you need.
Here is links for that files (from my public dropbox folder). I make archives with different extensions.
There is a txt file with path in it in each folder, try copy to the same folder and give feedback.

[7z archive](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9012508/mfplat/mfplat.7z)

[RAR archive](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9012508/mfplat/mfplat.rar)

[ZIP archive](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9012508/mfplat/mfplat.zip)

Comment: Thank you too friend (by the way we still don't know the reason).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I tried this solution despite the possible dangers and it still did not work for me. The reason is that the dlls posted by Arterius are for the 64 bit version of Windows. I am on a 32 bit Win 7 OS. 
I tried installing the WP7 SDK on another PC using the same installer and surprisingly, it worked perfectly. The only difference between these two machines was that on my work laptop(where I had the issue), The version of the OS was Windows 7N(This version does not have media player bundled). And on my other computer(where the installer worked perfectly), the version was one which had Windows media player installed. I found the [media update](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16546&hash=JghayGuFHDu45upIfn6rrGKux3yUnJQX/OgVvZsdET6S8MFEsqvEfOAuCvGlsViuspT5vBZecwnjUOgGJVxyow==) to get Windows media player installed, downloaded and installed it and then restarted and tried the emulator. Not Surprisingly, it worked perfectly.

*Microsoft works in mysterious ways!!!*